# Why does the cost of constraints violation parameter affect training time in an SVM?

Tags: r, svm, optimization

In R, I'm using the ksvm function from the kernlab package. My data has about 100,000 rows and 800 columns, so it can take an hour or more to train the SVM depending on the kernel.

One thing I have noticed is that the C parameter affects training time significantly, while only slightly affecting results. From the docs, C is:

```
cost of constraints violation (default:  1) this is the ‘C’-constant of the regular-
ization term in the Lagrange formulation.
```

Specifically, I believe C controls how hard or soft the margin is.

In my case, the training time when C = 0.1 is about 5 times faster than when C = 1, and the accuracy is only about 0.5% less. Why would the margin "hardness" affect the training time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ksvm` uses the [SMO algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_minimal_optimization), which solves a sequence of subproblems. Each involves a pair of variables, so there are $n(n-1)/2$ possible subproblems if $n$ is the number of samples. Usually, you won't have to solve every pair to reach the optimum. Each subproblem is selected *because some of the involved variables violate the constraints.* So, when you make the margin harder, you probably activate constraints on more points and end up solving more subproblems.